# Etymologically, why do "ser" and "estar" exist? / Etimológicamente, ¿por qué existen "ser" y "estar"?

Tags: etimología, verbos, cópulas, comparación-de-idiomas, preguntas-canónicas

> This is a [canonical question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) / Esta es una [pregunta canónica](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674)

***Ser*** and ***estar*** both mean "**to be**" in English. I understand this and also understand when to use each.

Why, however, do these two verbs exist?

Since Portuguese is similar in this respect, is there a common Old Spanish or perhaps Latin root?

---

***Ser*** y ***estar*** significan lo mismo en inglés: "**to be**".

Entiendo que cada uno tiene sus normas de uso y que se usa en diferentes ámbitos. Sin embargo, ¿por qué existen los dos verbos?

Dado que el portugués tiene la misma característica, ¿hay algún tipo de español antiguo común entre estas dos lenguas? ¿O puede que una raíz latina?

Comment: Also in Italian: _essere_ and _stare_.

Comment: Could be worse: in other languages there are 3+ verbs

Comment: @user13566 could you cite an example, please?

Comment: @Darkhogg: from somewhere in internet (can't recall) Japanese has copula verbs "da " / "desu [= polite version of "da"]" that would most often be translated as "to be" in English. Japanese also has two verbs "aru" & "iru" corresponding to English "to be". They are existential verbs, not copula verbs. "Aru" is used for inanimate objects including plants, whereas "iru" is used for people and animals although there are exceptions to this.  Add to this the polite forms like "arimasu", "imasu", extra-polite "irasshiaru" ...

Comment: @user13566 in fact, "desu" is a contraction of "de arimasu", from verb "aru", so technically they only have "aru" and "iru".

Comment: @user13566 of course I was talking about old uses of the verb "aru". Nowadays the verbs "aru" and "iru" have the uses you said. But this is a chat that may go forever and this is not the place. :-)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo: As I said, I have little knowledge on this, so I'll take your word that in Japanese there are only two verbs for the English "to be", and that it was a mistake on my part thinking otherwise.

Comment: Basque also has two: "egon" *estar* and "izan" *ser*. I suspect that it is due to the influence of Spanish, but this is pure speculation.

Comment: @camarones95 Wow that’s fascinating. This seems like a Linguistics question in the making

Comment: In French, the weird conjugation of "être" is a mix of sum and sto!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Way back in the times of the Latin language, there were two different verbs, but not with the same meaning as today:

- **sum, es, esse, fui**<sup>1</sup>, meaning "to be" (Spanish: "ser", "estar", "haber"). This was the main copulative verb in old Latin, i.e. it was used to connect two words or clauses.  It was used also as an auxiliary verb.  We use *haber* ("to have") as the auxiliary verb in modern Spanish. (Italian still uses the verb *essere* as an auxiliary.)
- **stô, -âs, -âre, stetî, statum**, meaning "to remain" or "to stand" (Spanish: "estar de pie"). This is the tricky part. This verb (infinitive: *stâre*) is the ancestor of the modern Spanish *estar*, and is a cognate of the English verbs *stay* and *stand*. If you think about it, when you are standing, you are positioned in a given place at a given time.  That is precisely the main difference between *ser* and *estar*. The latter can be taken to mean the same as *ser*, but *at a given moment in time*.

So these two verbs are the roots of today's *ser* and *estar*. But the DLE says that *[ser](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xe5Brrm)* comes from *seer*, so what verb is that? *Seer* is an evolution of the Latin verb *sedere*, "to settle" or "to sit" (Spanish: "estar sentado"), by the loss of the middle -d- (something not uncommon) and the final -e (as happened with every verb in the Iberian Romance languages). As Vulgar Latin evolved, the verb *seer* merged with the old Latin verb *esse* (now *essere*), and soon the verb *seer* lost the meaning of "being seated," just as the verb *stare* lost the meaning of "being in a standing position." But both of them kept, respectively, the sense of being permanent ("ser") and being transitory ("estar").

More specifically, the *essere* verb denoted *essence*, while the *stare* verb denoted *state*.

So, sentences from Latin (that used the *esse* verb), such as

> *Vir **est** in foro* (The man is in the marketplace)

became

> *(H)omo **stat** in foro*

which now uses the verb *stare*, since what was perceived was that *the man was standing in the marketplace.* As time went by, the verb began to be used just to express that someone was in a given place at a given time.

Thus, we come to the age of Old Spanish, the 10th century onwards. Time to cite the most famous story from these years: *Cantar de Myo Çid*:

> Grado a ti Sennor Padre que **estas** en alto.
>
> Y **estava** donna Ximena con çinco duennas de pro, **rogando** a san Pero e al Criador.

These examples show that the verb *estar* (now the final -e was dropped) was being used the same as the nowadays version, both to mean *being in a place* and as an auxiliary verb for the continuous present (*estaba rogando*).

The verb *ser* also had already its current infinitive form, but was still used as an auxiliary verb in place of today's *haber*. But it was used already to form the passive voice. Examples:

> En yra del rey Alffonsso yo **sere metido**.
>
> Assi **es** vuestra ventura, grandes **son** vuestras ganançias.

Nonetheless, we still see some expressions that contradict the current way:

> [...] en vuestras manos **son** las arcas.

But this could be because here the verb *ser* is used to mean *to have*: in fact the English translation reads *ye have the coffers two*.

You can find much more information about the uses of the verbs *ser* and *estar* in the Old Spanish in *"Ser" y "estar". Orígenes de sus funciones en el «Cantar de Mio Cid»* from Spanish writer José María Saussol (publicaciones de la Universidad de Sevilla, 1978). [Abstract here](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/thesaurus/pdf/35/TH_35_002_187_0.pdf) (PDF).

---

<sub>Footnotes:</sub>

<sub>1: Fui (Latin - the Spanish is a descendant) is unusual as it comes from the Proto-Italic stem *fu- "to become". [Source](http://spanishetym.com/search?query=fui)</sub>

Comment: found a good source. http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Ser-Estar-Origen%20y%20evoluci%C3%B3n.htm

Comment: @celerno added information from that page, thank you!

Comment: I knew a bit about sum/sto, but I hadn't been aware of the role that sedo apparently played -- fascinating!

Comment: Just FYI, taking bits and pieces of a different verb's conjugation into another, as in the case with *esse* forms being replaced by *sedo* forms, is called [suppletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion). That's what happens in the past tense of English *to go* (where *went* comes from the verb *to wend*).

Comment: Why did you give the second-person singular present active form among the other principal parts for *sum* and *sto*?

Comment: Charlie, since this is a canonical Q-A, I have some suggestions for making your answer even more useful.  When you introduce a technical term like *copulative*, could you explain it?  Also, when you give a definition in Spanish, could you provide an English version in parentheses (e.g. for "ser, estar, haber")?

Comment: @aparente001 that's a nice idea. I've made some changes to the first part. Feel free to propose more changes, or even modify the answer yourself, as I'm not confident enough to translate into English the examples from _Cantar de Myo Çid_.

Comment: I know nothing about Old Latin and Vulgar Latin.  When you have a chance, please check what I did, especially the timeline aspect.

Answer (score 7):

**Why do `ser` and `estar` exist?**

They have different roots, in particular the Spanish verb `ser` has multiple roots:

- The infinitive (e.g. `ser`), the conditionals (e.g. `sería`) and the future form (e.g. `seré`) come from the Latin `sedēre` (present active infinitive of `sedeō`).
- The other forms (e.g. `es`, `fui`) come from the Latin `esse` (present active infinitive of `sum`) or the vulgar Latin `essere` derived from it.

On the other hand the Spanish verb `estar` comes from the Latin `stāre` (present active infinitive of `stō`).

---

To compare it to English, the English verb `am` shares the Proto-Indo-European (PIE) root with the Latin `sum`. That PIE root already had "both" meanings.

**Where is the Latin `sedēre` in English?** It is the root for the English verb `to sit`.

**Where is the Latin `stāre` in English?** It is the root for the English verb `to stay`, it is also related to the nouns `state`, `status`, `station` and `stance`.

**Note**: do not confuse with the English verb `to stare` which doesn't have its root in Latin.

So I would argue that the closest equivalent to the Spanish verb `estar` in English is the verb `to stay`. Yet, the English verb `to stay` means `to continue to be in a place or condition` while the Spanish verb `estar` lacks the the connotation of `continue to be`.

---

Since the shared PIE root for the Latin `sum` and English `am` had already both meanings, we must conclude that at some point Spanish preferred to differentiate `estar` from `ser`... In fact, Old Spanish (circa the XI century) still used the verb `ser` with both meaning※. It is unclear exactly when `estar` replaced `ser` for locations and conditions.

※: Example from "Cantar de Mio Cid": `El vno es en parayso` would be <strike>`El`</strike>`uno está en`*`el`*`paraíso` in modern Spanish.

---

**Sources:**

Wikitionary:

- [Spanish ser](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ser#Spanish)
- [Latin sedeo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sedeo#Latin)
- [Latin esse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/esse#Latin)
- [Latin sum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sum#Latin)
- [Latin sto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sto#Latin)

Wikipedia:

- [Romance copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_copula)
- [Old Spanish Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Spanish_language)
- [Cantar de Mio Cid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantar_de_Mio_Cid)

Etymonline:

- [English sit](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sit)
- [English stay](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stay)
- [English stare](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stare)

Newcastle University:

- [History of the Spanish Verb](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/hisverb.htm)

Diccionario Etimológico de Chile

- [Etimología de SER](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?ser)
- [Etimología de ESTAR](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?estar)