# ¿Existe alguna palabra registrada en español que haya perdido la -d- de la última sílaba?

Tags: etimología, ortografía, dle, participio, síncopa

Soy de la opinión de que, en un futuro más lejano que cercano, el idioma español evolucionará y acabará perdiendo la *-d-* de los participios y de muchas otras palabras que acaban con el patrón vocal+d+vocal (siendo las vocales diferentes), porque el habla relajada tiende a omitirla sin importar de dónde sea el hablante. De hecho, a mí hoy día me resulta más natural decir *peo* que *[pedo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SJF2rm9)*, esta última me suena hasta cursi pero solo esa está registrada en la RAE.

Entiendo que la evolución del lenguaje será lenta, dado que para eso está la RAE que "limpia, **fija** y da esplendor" (sería curioso preguntar cómo habría evolucionado el español sin la RAE para fijar el idioma, pero como entra dentro del terreno de la especulación me abstendré de hacerlo). Sin embargo, como curiosidad, ¿ha empezado ya esa transición? Si es así, ¿desde cuándo? ¿Existe alguna palabra registrada en la RAE que con el tiempo haya perdido esa *-d-* de la última sílaba o que etimológicamente debería llevarla pero no es así? Si es posible, que la pérdida no haya sido para crear una palabra o acepción nueva sino que la versión sincopada haya sustituido a la original sin variar el significado.

---

Ejemplo: pensé que igual la palabra *bacalao* provendría del latín **bacalatus* y entonces etimológicamente debería llevar una *-d-* pero no, viene del euskera *[bakailao](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4jHz5SC)*. También recuerdo la [etimología del verbo *ser*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18441/12637) (*sedere* > *seer* > *ser*), pero la *-d-* que perdió es intermedia e iba entre dos vocales iguales.

---

Relacionada: [Se dice humareda, pero en mi vida he escuchado algo que no sea humarea](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24362/12637)

Comment: Sin la RAE sería un desmadre total. Sin una academia de la lengua el latin a evolucionado en portugués, español, catalán, francés, italiano, rumano, y las demás lenguas románicas, cada una de ellas con variantes y regionalismos.  Como ejemplo de una palabra que posiblemente haya perdido la `d`: **grao** =  *desembarcadero o playa que sirve de desembarcadero*. Viene del catalán *grau, grada*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**-ado, -ada**

- ollado → [ollao](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R1UNVZn), rodado → [rodao](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Wal7CxT) (Ast., León y Pal.), sobado → [sobao](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y3tw0UJ), tablado → [tablao](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YsqyTFj), ripiado → [perico] [ripiao](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WVQuMKY) (Dom.), tonada → [toná](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a0BaFqo), alboreada → [alboreá](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1Y85Ec1)

**-ido, ida**

- hipido → jipido → [jipío](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MU6QxKO), tepidus → [tibio](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=ZiKy1sZ), limpidus → [limpio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NLRTLp0), *mustidus → [mustio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q9oHwZN) <sup>¿?</sup>, Lócrida → [locria](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=NYMhn8V%7CNYP5w9Z)

**-udo, -uda**

- castudo → [castúo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7sMeZ77), agalludo → [agallú](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1308CQG) (P. Rico), picaruda → [picarúa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Stb7he9) (Murcia)<sup>[1](http://www.usc.es/gl/servizos/snl/terminoloxia/uip/arquivo/numero_146.html) [2](http://www.usc.es/revistas/index.php/elg/article/viewFile/343/343)</sup>

**-ador, -adora**

- tocador → [tocaor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zw2e8nG), bailador → [bailaor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4nGSyY0), cantador → [cantaor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7BVFreb)

**-eda**

- moneda → [moa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PRkcQfu) <sup>¿? [3](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/el-delincuente-espanol-el-lenguaje-estudio-filologico-psicologico-y-sociologico-con-dos-vocabularios-jergales--0/html/ff0f09f0-82b1-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_66.html)</sup>, lampreda → [lamprea](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MrKz0DJ)

**Misc**

- cañadilla → [cañaílla](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=ca%C3%B1a%C3%ADlla) (And.), fastidium → [hastío](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K2lG6oa), [soledad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YGkk3NL) → soleá, cadena  → [caena](https://dirae.es/palabras/caena)

---

### Préstamos

No es exactamente lo que buscas, pero también hay unas palabras así prestadas de lenguas vecinas:

- `lat` gradus → `cat` grau → `esp` grao
- `lat` sedes → `cat/arag` seu → `esp` [seo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XcWVLM9)
- `port` capim-melado → `esp` [capin melao](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7JkJ6xp)

Answer (score 4):

Buscando en el DLE [palabras terminadas en `-ao`](http://dle.rae.es/?w=ao&m=32), encuentro varias candidatas como por ejemplo: **cortao**, **ripiao**, **rodao**, **sobao** o **tablao**.

Lamentablemente, ahora mismo no funciona el servicio de definiciones, solo el de búsqueda, así que no puedo acceder a la definición para comprobarlo. Pero vaya, me sorprendería que dichas palabras tengan otros orígenes que no sean los participios terminados en `-ado` de *cortar*, *ripiar*, *rodar*, *sobar* o *(en)tablar* respectivamente.

Comment: Pues sorpréndete. [_Cortao_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B1covdT): del francés antiguo _courtaud_. [_Ripiao_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WVQuMKY) solo se usa en la expresión _perico ripiao_ y no da etimología. [_Rodao_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Wal7CxT) sí hace referencia a _rodado_ pero solo a una acepción concreta y muy localizada. [_Sobao_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y3tw0UJ) sí viene de _sobado_ pero hace referencia a una nueva acepción de la palabra que no tiene que ver con _sobar_ (tal vez tendría que haber especificado eso, lo mismo pasa con [_tablao_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YsqyTFj)).  :-)

Comment: Rectifico: mientras que _tablao_ introdujo una nueva acepción a _tablado_, la palabra _sobao_ es de inclusión reciente y aparece como sinónimo de _sobado_ en España, manteniendo la acepción previa, así que sí puede ser una posible respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Por dejarla aquí registrada, una palabra que me resulta muy familiar y que no imaginaba que iba a estar en el DLE:

> [**chuchurrío, a**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=92CYVyt)
>
> De or. expr.; cf. *chocho<sup>2</sup>* y el desus. *chuchurrar* 'despachurrar'.
>
> 1. adj. coloq. Marchito o ajado. U. t. en sent. fig.

Lo curioso de este caso es que la versión con *d* no está en el diccionario (no viene *chuchurrar*), así que en este caso la palabra ha entrado directamente así en el DLE, a pesar de que su uso en mi tierra es de sobra conocido:

> *Ese personaje amarillo
>
>   Ese lindo pajarillo
>
>   Me ha dejado solo y aburrido
>
>   Y hasta las flores se han chuchurrido.*
>
> Letra de *El canario*, del grupo "No me pises que llevo chanclas".

Ahora que lo pienso, *chuchurrido* sería el participio de *chuchurrir*, no de *chuchurrar*... aunque da igual, tampoco viene en el DLE.