# El fenómeno de la pérdida del -d- en los participios, ¿puede ocurrir en palabras que no sean participios?

Tags: verbos, pronunciación, participio, morfología

Sé que es común que en el habla uno no use la -d- en la última sílaba de los verbos participios, por ejemplo, que diga 'partío' en lugar de 'partido'.

¿Pero ese fenómeno es posible con palabras que terminen en -ado/-edo/-ido y no sean verbos en el participio? Por ejemplo, ¿es posible escuchar a alguien decir 'cuadrao' en lugar de 'cuadrado'?

Comment: Sí, se escucha mucho decir cosas como "el magistrao", o "qué mal educao" (adjetivo, aunque también participio).

Comment: Sí: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28147/existe-alguna-palabra-registrada-en-espa%c3%b1ol-que-haya-perdido-la-d-de-la-%c3%baltim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí. Como [indica el DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/d) en su entrada para la letra *d* (**negritas** mías):

> 2. Lo más destacable en relación con la pronunciación de este sonido es su debilitamiento en posición intervocálica, especialmente notable en la terminación -ado propia de los participios de los verbos de la primera conjugación **y de algunos nombres**. En el habla coloquial de algunas zonas, especialmente en España, el debilitamiento es extremo y llega con frecuencia a la total omisión de la /d/, fenómeno que debe evitarse en el habla esmerada: [kansáo] por *cansado*, **[peskáo] por *pescado***. Aún más vulgar y rechazable resulta la pérdida de la /d/ en las terminaciones *-ido*, *-ida*: [komío] por *comido*, [benía] por *venida*.

Es decir, esto ocurre en participios y en nombres, y ocurre con más frecuencia en palabras terminadas en *-ado* que en palabras terminadas en *-ido*. Aunque el DPD solo habla de participios y nombres, también ocurre en adjetivos. En particular, el ejemplo que pones me recuerda a la expresión coloquial "*estar cuadrado*", que en algunas zonas de España significa "estar fuerte" o "estar musculoso" ([ejemplo](https://urbanian.mundodeportivo.com/cinetv/6919/el-brutal-entrenamiento-que-siguio-christian-bale-para-estar-cuadrado-en-batman-despues-de-estar-esqueletico-en-el-maquinista)). Diría que absolutamente todas las veces que he oído esta expresión coloquial, la he oído sin el sonido "d" final: "*[está cuadrao]*".