# ¿De dónde viene "¿Qué Ha Pasao'?"?

Tags: letras-de-canciones

Hay una canción que se llama "¿Qué Ha Pasao'?". La palabra "pasao" es extraña en este lugar, "pasado" tendría sentido pero no "pasao". Sin embargo, la letra parece ser española. ¿Alguien me puede explicar esta palabra?

Comment: When I hear people speaking _pasado_ often sounds like _pasao_ and the same goes for all the similar forms.

Comment: Acerca de la debilitación del sonido /d/ entre vocales, puedes leer la explicación en esta respuesta: [Pronunciación letras "d", "b" y "v" entre vocales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17242/6915). Y la opinión de la Real Academia sobre la pérdida de esa /d/ se presenta en esta otra respuesta: [El fenómeno de la pérdida del -d- en los participios, ¿puede ocurrir en palabras que no sean participios?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/37059/6915).

Comment: Viene de Andalucia. :) :) It's pasado, of course. The intervocalic d is dropped. :) Those intervocalic d's often disappear in southern Spanish speech.  ¿Qué has compra[d]o? And it has carried over at times to some LA countries.  ¿ Cóma has baila[d]o? How did you dance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una forma abreviada de pronunciar el verbo cuando está en participio. Ejemplos como ese sobran en el lenguaje coloquial y hasta pueden encontrarse incluso en los sustantivos y con otras palabras que tengan al final consonantes que no necesariamente sean la *d*:

> La paré' es blanca.

> El ferné' está re puro.

> Mi amigo e' un porfiao'.

> ¡No te vayá' a perder, eh!.

> [¿Qué mirá', bobo? ¡Andá, andá pa'llá!](https://youtu.be/2zfzaoioxQg)

Según el contexto y la zona, la práctica puede ser aceptable en el ámbito oral. No obstante, en el lenguaje escrito la misma se considera muy informal y no es estándar, así que deberías evitarla, sobre todo si justamente vas a escribir un documento formal. Algo smilar ocurre en el inglés cuando se pierde la g en palabras terminadas en -ing (going --> *goin'*, etc).

Comment: Eso no es verdad, lamento. Los andaluces suelen hablar sin la d intervocalica y no siempre informalmente.

Comment: @Lambie Pero yo no afirmé eso, no es que esté mal **hablar así**, yo dije que hay que evitarlo **al escribir**. Lo voy a agregar por si hubo una mala interpretación.

Comment: Pero dijiste eso: No obstante esta práctica se considera muy informal. Y no lo es para los Andaluces, p.ej.

Comment: Porque me faltó aclarar que me refería a lo escrito. Ya lo reformulé.

Comment: The `'` kinda makes sense then too, however the confusing part is that the `'` is written _after_ the `o` and not before, despite the dropped `d` normally being written _before_ the `o`. If a letter was dropped, I'd normally write the `'` in place of that letter, i.e. `pasa'o` and not `pasao'` (in English or German at least, e.g. `isn't` and not `isnt'`). Is that different in Spanish then? Interesting!

Comment: @CherryDT In Spanish, no apostrophe is used to show a dropped letter. That only happens in English. That apostrophe is a typo.

Comment: @Lambie It's part of the official song name though. So perhaps it's "artistic freedom" then. Thank you!

Comment: @Lambie Hmmm but in tac's answer there is also an apostrophe in every example... So probably not a typo... And it's always at the end except in pa'llá - why?

Comment: @CherryDTThat is just to show you. I repeat: apostrophes are not used to show letters left out. Also, I do not agree with some of those examples as they are not like the ones where an intervocalic consonant is missing. HIs examples are not like your question. They are different. (See Rodrigo's comment above for how yours is).

Comment: It's at the end, because in tac's examples, a consonant is left off the end: La pare**d** es blanca. In what Rodrigo and I are saying, a consonant disappears in an intervocalic position: el pasa[do] becomes el pasao.